# URL Shortening Site

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, apache, url-rewriting

I am working on a URL shortening site which uses PHP, MySQL and Apache. General idea of URL shortening as I look at open source projects: user gives a URL link and the system gets ID for that link from database. Then convert the ID X base system (I am using base 36). Then use Apache mod_rewrite and create shortened URL and then redirect.  Do all of the URL shortening sites work like that or do some use a different algorithm other than this?  And any idea for making a difference from other URL shortening systems?

Comment: The question you have to ask is: why do you want to make another URL shortening site?  If you want to make something exactly the same as what already exists, it seems rather a waste of time.  If, on the other hand, you want to do something different, you're the only one who knows what that is.

Comment: i wanna add more features like
1-firefox plugin
2-auto copy clipboard
3-post to delicious,stumble like sites
4-and i am thinking to use google safe browse integration

Comment: I see no reason not to recreate the wheel, because at the end of the day you have learned how to build your own wheel.

Comment: first reason to get into project is learn the process of shortening url and i see no harm at creating another system that work in the same way, if its a good service , why not become famous like bit.ly or tinyurl with plus features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are quite on the right way.

One thing I would not do like you said, though, is about this part :

> then use apache mod_rewrite and create
>   shorten url and then redirect.

I don't think I'd create an Apache RewriteRule, nor use `mod_rewrite`.

When receiving an short url, like `short.com/MYID`, Id would :

- decrypt the "MYID" part to the id number in DB
- fetch the URL from database
- just redirect to that URL from some server code (like PHP, using the [`header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function)

A bit like this I guess :

```
// fetch $urlFull from DB (corresponding to the MYID received in GET)
header('HTTP/1.x 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: ' . $urlFull);
die;
```

(edit) If by `mod_rewrite` you meant "*transform short.com/MYID to short.com/id=MYID*", oh, yes, in this case, of course !

I'm using something like this on one of my sites, btw :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?hash=$1   [L]
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/) (twitter uses this). There are some APIs which you can use to call and fetch shortened URLs.

Also talk about shortening URLs, you can simply use a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `urls` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `url` text NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Where you can have the `id` (in base 36 to prevent exhaustion of 32 bit integers) to be the shortened id - http://host/?id

and when you call the URL http://host/?As2dD24B, it will look up the matching ID and URL, then redirects to the URL. simple?

Also keep in mind that you can expand your base 36. I am assuming that your base 36 is:
a-z and 0-9. You can add in A-Z (another 26) and other symbols (such as ?,:*&^%$#@).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something different from other URL shortening sites, figure out a way to make sure the links don't break if your site goes away!  I don't know how to do this, I think it's probably impossible...

Comment: You can set up your servers on Amazon EC2 with Elastic IP's. This would give good load-balancing.

Answer (score 2):

Just a security note: Do not redirect directly to the site from a shortened url if it's not under your control/domain - have a landing page where the user can see the actual url and decide whether to continue or not...

Comment: And make sure the visitor can flag the site as spam.

Comment: That ruins a URL shorter for me. Allow an option to add ? to a link to get its details - similar to br.st and bit.ly

Comment: Well as just loading a web site can ruin your day/computer we should teach users to look at the URL first and try to figure out if it's what they wanted... sounds paranoid perhaps but a lot of attacks are based on the user being directed to a malicious site.

Comment: being able to flag the link as spam would be a good idea, but putting a pause into the process? That's just a bad idea.. slows the system down, and makes the user's experience less than ideal

Comment: TinyURL at request will place a cookie on your computer which it will parse and present a preview for you as an opt-in... I still think redirecting without some preview of the destination domain is completely insane security-wise - but users are lazy I guess :/

Answer (score 2):

Being related to the subject... [Url Shorteners: Destroying the Web Since 2002](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001276.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using YOURLS which is a robust open source package to do exactly this. It's PHP/MySQL based.

http://yourls.org/#Install

From the about page:

*YOURLS is a small set of PHP scripts that will allow you to run your own URL shortening service (a la TinyURL). You can make it private or public, you can pick custom keyword URLs, it comes with its own API.*