# What is needed to write your own URL shortener?

Tags: php, mysql, url-rewriting

I want to write my own URL shortener using php and mysql as a tester to see how much I know about the two languages? However I don't know what is needed to do so or where to start. Please could someone give me a list of what needs to be done in order to create/write a successful URL shortener?

Comment: Creating a random string with letter and numbers, with max length and then assign this string to an URL and save it into MySQL?

Comment: Related/dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383145/url-shortening-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a short domain name.

Then you can have a simple MySQL table with two columns: Id (the primary key with auto increment) and Url. Which should probably be a TEXT or something. Since varchar 255 might be too short.

Then set up your .htaccess so that a url like domain.com/a21s1 gets converted to domain.com?url=a21s1

That'd be something along the lines of:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:.*)domain\.com/(.*)/?$ domain.com?url=$1
```

Then in php do something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
    $url = base_convert((int)$_GET['url'],36,10);
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT `Url` FROM `My Table` WHERE `Id` = '.$url);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $url = $row[0];
}else
    $url = 'http://domain.com/yourhomepage';

header('location: '.$url);
```

You'd also want to have sanity checks when users input a new url to add you would regex it to make sure it's a url, and if it's missing `http://` prepend it to the url.

Comment: Ah, nice touch with the URL rewrite!

Answer (score 1):

I just done [my-gplus](http://my-gplus.org)

- use as short domain as possible
- use .htaccess rewrites to create short tail after /
- do not bother users with "Thank you for using ... redirecting to" when user is being redirected
- do not force users to register
- allow users to register & view their statistics

.htaccess could look like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ redirect.php?url=$1 [L]
```