# Fast URL encrypt in javascript, decrypt in php

Tags: php, javascript, encryption

I have a url with several parameters is use for a http request. It looks like this:

```
http://www.url.com/site.php?parameter1=x&parameter2=y
```

I would like to make sth like this in javascript:

```
http://www.url.com/data=wafseghsgse or http://www.url.com/site/?data=wafseghsgse
```

And in php I would get the "old" url back to work with it.

I am looking for the fastest way to do this, not the most secure one. To save a key for encryption I would use the database or maybe session (safe?).

Looking for your great ideas.

Comment: You are looking to build a URL shortener. There is plenty of information about how to build one out there. Related: [URL Shortening Site](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1383145) and [URL shortener: best encoding method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2375968)

Comment: @quentin because i do not like the user to see the parameter sent maybe user_id etc.

Comment: Will you send the key to the browser for encryption?

Comment: Encrypting something using javascript on the clients browser will not make you application secure.

Comment: @Salman. No i would get it from db or store it in session. Last one i do not have any clue if it is save or not.

Comment: @RuvenJR.Maerson — If you are encrypting the data with client side JavaScript, then the unencrypted version *must* be available to the client, so the user can see it. Attempting to keep these things secret is fruitless and adds unnecessary complexity that can add bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a fast obfuscate method with no care about security, you can use [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13), you have javascript ROT13 implementations in [Where is my one-line implementation of rot13 in JavaScript going wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617647/where-is-my-one-line-implementation-of-rot13-in-javascript-going-wrong) and then in PHP you have [str_rot13()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php) to decrypt the javascript version.

Comment: yes this is sth. i could use. I will give it a try. In addition to SSL this is a good solution i think.